# Google Material Design - disabling a switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design

I'm unable to find any actual web based code examples that demonstrates how to go about disabling a switch for Google Material Design JavaScript.

I've tried `foo.setAttribute('disabled');`, `foo.setAttribute(disabled);`, and `foo.setAttribute('state', 'disabled');` to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried benvc's solution along with a ton of different variations of it with no success - I'm sure it's just something funky with the code I'm working with.

I ended up disabling the switch by changing the element's CSS properties:

```
elem.setAttribute("style","pointer-events: none;");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable a material design component switch with javascript simply by setting the disabled property to true.

```
const elem = document.querySelector('#switch-id');
elem.disabled = true;
```

Answer (score -1):

var switch = new mdc.switchControl.MDCSwitch(document.getElementByclassName('mdc-switch'));

//for enable
switch.disabled = false;

//for disable
switch.disabled = true;